# Most efficient way to attach properties from one object to another if certain key:values match?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's say I have two data sources that are fairly large, 3000+ entries each. They might look something like this...

```
const arOfObj1 = [
  { type: 'Something', properties: { name: 'ABC' } },
  { type: 'Something', properties: { name: 'DEF' } },
  { type: 'Something', properties: { name: 'GHI' } },
  ...and so on...
];

const arOfObj2 = [
  { name: 'ABC', stats: { age: 1, other: "Something" } },
  { name: 'DEF', stats: { age: 2, isEnrolled: true } },
  { name: 'GHI', stats: { age: 3 } },
  ...and so on...
];
```

What would be the most efficient way of finding the `name` property that matches in each object, and appending the `stats{...}` (or other properties if they exist) from `arOfObj2` to `arOfObj1`? so I would end up with something like this

```
const newArOfObj1 = [
  { type: 'Something', properties: { name: 'ABC', stats: { age: 1, other: "Something" } },
  { type: 'Something', properties: { name: 'DEF', stats: { age: 2, isEnrolled: true } },
  { type: 'Something', properties: { name: 'GHI', stats: { age: 3 } },
  ...and so on...
]
```

My initial thought was to do something like this...

```
arOfObj1.forEach(obj1 => {
  arOfObj2.forEach(obj2 => {
    if (obj1.properties.name === obj2.name) {
    obj1.stats = obj2.stats
    }
  })
});
```

Just not sure if there's a better way than to loop through `arOfObj2` for each entry in `arOfObj1`

Comment: Please add to your question the code you have tried.

Comment: @jmargolisvt - done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory is usually not the issue in the JavaScript applications and 3000+ array of objects is not that big for a modern machine. I'll have to assume that you're looking for a speed increase.

In case I am wrong and you're looking for something that would be more memory efficient then ignore my response and look in to batching with something like [js batch](https://github.com/visionmedia/batch) to avoid loading up memory all at once and instead spreading the memory load across batches.

---

Assuming we're looking for a fastest way to complete the task.

## Code:

1. map/find

```
arOfObj1.map(o => ({
  ...o,
  properties: {
    ...o.properties,
    stats: arOfObj2.find(a => a.name === o.properties.name).stats
  }
}));
```

2. Simple double for loop

```
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arOfObj1.length; i++) {
  let o = arOfObj1[i];
  let stats;
  for (let j = 0; j < arOfObj2.length; j++) {
    if (stats) break;
    let a = arOfObj2[j];
    if (a.name === o.properties.name) {
      stats = a.stats;
    }
  }
  result.push({
    ...o, properties: {...o.properties, stats}
  });
}
```

3. Map set - while I was at it @programmerRaj posted his answer with this solution so look at his response, but I'll include it in my speed test below.

## So now we can test these for speed:

Filling both arrays with 5000 items and running all solutions while measuring time.

```
let arOfObj1 = [];
let arOfObj2 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
  arOfObj1.push({type: 'Something', properties: { name: `name${i}` }});
  arOfObj2.push({name: `name${i}`, stats: { age: i, other: "Something" }});
}

console.time('map/find');
arOfObj1.map(o => ({
  ...o,
  properties: {
    ...o.properties,
    stats: arOfObj2.find(a => a.name === o.properties.name).stats
  }
}));
console.timeEnd('map/find');

console.time('for loop');
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arOfObj1.length; i++) {
  let o = arOfObj1[i];
  let stats;
  for (let j = 0; j < arOfObj2.length; j++) {
    if (stats) break;
    let a = arOfObj2[j];
    if (a.name === o.properties.name) {
      stats = a.stats;
    }
  }
  result.push({
    ...o, properties: {...o.properties, stats}
  });
}
console.timeEnd('for loop');

console.time('programmerRaj\'s solution');
var names = new Map();
for(var i = 0, len = arOfObj2.length; i < len; i++){
  var obj = arOfObj2[i];
  names.set(obj.name, obj.stats);
}
for(var i = 0, len = arOfObj1.length; i < len; i++){
  var properties = arOfObj1[i].properties;
  properties.stats = names.get(properties.name);
}
console.timeEnd('programmerRaj\'s solution');
```

Running test with Node lts (12) I get the following results:

```
map/find: 189.902ms
for loop: 188.912ms
programmerRaj's solution: 3.236ms
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the most efficient way is, and I don't really know how the memory works in javascript, but I have a way that works.

```js
const arOfObj1 = [
  { type: 'Something', properties: { name: 'ABC' }},
  { type: 'Something', properties: { name: 'DEF' }},
  { type: 'Something', properties: { name: 'GHI' }}
];

const arOfObj2 = [
  { name: 'ABC', stats: { age: 1, other: "Something" } },
  { name: 'DEF', stats: { age: 2, isEnrolled: true } },
  { name: 'GHI', stats: { age: 3 } }
];

var names = new Map();

for(var i = 0, len = arOfObj2.length; i < len; i++){
  var obj = arOfObj2[i];
  names.set(obj.name, obj.stats);
}

for(var i = 0, len = arOfObj1.length; i < len; i++){
  var properties = arOfObj1[i].properties;
  properties.stats = names.get(properties.name);
}

console.log(arOfObj1);
```

What it does is loop through each object, saving the name and stats as the key and value in a `Map`. Then it loops through the first array of objects, adding the stats property that it gets from `Map.get`.